# ldconfig: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once

Tags: 12.10, libraries, shared-library

I'm running 12.10.

I'm trying to run an application that needs `libglut.so.3`. I installed `freeglut3` and I can see the library located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. But when I run the application, it tells me that it can't find the library.

When I run `ldconfig -v | grep glut` I get

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
        libglut.so.3 -> libglut.so.3.9.0
```

What does it mean when it says the path is given more than once, and does this have anything to do with why the application can't find the library?

Comment: Did you ever find out? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Check `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*`.

Comment: I've seen it too, but it appears to be only an informational message, not any sort of trouble.  

Here is a similar message from ldconfig -v, "/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring" before this line "ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> ld-2.19.so".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ldconfig.real searches /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu by default.

On my system there is a configuration file in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf that included these directories, hence causing the error.

I then discovered that this file is created by the libc6 package. Thus, the /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf file can be safely deleted.

When you run ldconfig --verbose again, you will see that those two directories are still indexed.

Comment: I had the same issue and after deleting the "/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf" file, got rid of the error. Thank you very much

Comment: I had the same issue after deleting  the "/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf" file, still having the error:
$ sudo  ldconfig --verbose
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. The path is builtin now with `/sbin/ldconfig.real`. So this is harmless either way, can be ignored. or you can file a bug report.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug