# 2080 Ti stopped working randomly

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics, cuda

I had two working 2080Ti. After a linux (14.04) update, I started getting this error:

NVIDIA_SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

I tried the following (basically everything I could find in the internet) to fix it:

1. Purged all Nvidia installs and reinstalled using `apt-get install
   nvidia-drivers-418`
2. Tried reinstalling it from NVidia's source
3. Downgraded my kernel to `4.15.0-46-generic` from `4.15.0-47-generic` and repeated steps 1 and 2.
4. Installed cuda 10.1
5. Disabled secure boot

I have no idea what else to do.

[image: Output of error]

```
ldconfig -v | grep nvidia
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

        libnvidia-fbc.so.1 -> libnvidia-fbc.so.410.104
        libnvidia-compiler.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-compiler.so.410.104
        libnvidia-tls.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-tls.so.410.104
        libGLX_nvidia.so.0 -> libGLX_nvidia.so.410.104
        libnvidia-cfg.so.1 -> libnvidia-cfg.so.410.104
        libnvidia-ml.so.1 -> libnvidia-ml.so.410.104
        libnvidia-opencl.so.1 -> libnvidia-opencl.so.410.104
        libnvidia-eglcore.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-eglcore.so.410.104
        libnvidia-glcore.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-glcore.so.410.104
        libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.1 -> libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.410.104
        libnvidia-glvkspirv.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-glvkspirv.so.410.104
        libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.410.104
        libEGL_nvidia.so.0 -> libEGL_nvidia.so.410.104
        libnvidia-rtcore.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-rtcore.so.410.104
        libnvidia-glsi.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-glsi.so.410.104
        libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1 -> libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.410.104
        libnvidia-ifr.so.1 -> libnvidia-ifr.so.410.104
        libnvidia-encode.so.1 -> libnvidia-encode.so.410.104
        libnvidia-cbl.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-cbl.so.410.104
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib32/ld-2.27.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

        libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2 -> libGLESv2_nvidia.so.410.104
        libnvidia-gtk3.so.418.56 -> libnvidia-gtk3.so.418.56
        libnvidia-gtk2.so.418.56 -> libnvidia-gtk2.so.418.56
        libnvidia-tls.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-tls.so.410.104
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ldconfig: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once](https://askubuntu.com/q/272369/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't correctly set library path. To verity that, run `ldconfig -v | grep nvidia` and see if outputs contain many `libnvidia*.so`.

Here are my outputs:

```
    libnvidia-glcore.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-glcore.so.410.104
    libnvidia-rtcore.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-rtcore.so.410.104
    libEGL_nvidia.so.0 -> libEGL_nvidia.so.410.104
    libnvidia-ifr.so.1 -> libnvidia-ifr.so.410.104
    libGLX_nvidia.so.0 -> libGLX_nvidia.so.410.104
    libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2 -> libGLESv2_nvidia.so.410.104
    libnvidia-tls.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-tls.so.410.104
    libnvidia-compiler.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-compiler.so.410.104
    libnvidia-egl-wayland.so.1 -> libnvidia-egl-wayland.so.1.1.0
    libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1 -> libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.410.104
    libnvidia-glsi.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-glsi.so.410.104
    libnvidia-eglcore.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-eglcore.so.410.104
    libnvidia-opencl.so.1 -> libnvidia-opencl.so.410.104
    libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-fatbinaryloader.so.410.104
    libnvidia-cbl.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-cbl.so.410.104
    libnvidia-container.so.1 -> libnvidia-container.so.1.0.2
    libnvidia-encode.so.1 -> libnvidia-encode.so.410.104
    libnvidia-ml.so.1 -> libnvidia-ml.so.410.104
    libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.1 -> libnvidia-ptxjitcompiler.so.410.104
    libnvidia-glvkspirv.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-glvkspirv.so.410.104
    libnvidia-fbc.so.1 -> libnvidia-fbc.so.410.104
    libnvidia-cfg.so.1 -> libnvidia-cfg.so.410.104

    libnvidia-gtk2.so.418.40.04 -> libnvidia-gtk2.so.418.40.04
    libnvidia-gtk3.so.418.40.04 -> libnvidia-gtk3.so.418.40.04
    libnvidia-tls.so.410.104 -> libnvidia-tls.so.410.104
```

To fix that, create a new file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/nvidia.conf` and edit:

```
/usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib
```

Make sure `/usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib` contains nvidia shared libraries. Execute `ldconfig -v | grep nvidia` again.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. It still does not work. I pasted the output above.